# The metadata path is not valid

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, metadata

The specified metadata path is not valid. A valid path must be either an existing directory, an existing file with extension '.csdl', '.ssdl', or '.msl', or a URI that identifies an embedded resource.

```
MetadataWorkspace wksp = new MetadataWorkspace(new string[] {
                  "res://*/ITBank.csdl|res://*/ITBank.ssdl|res://*/ITBank.msl" 
                  }, 
                  new Assembly[] { 
                  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() 
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the designer is not supported on `64 bit` machines. So, you need to ***copy*** two files `Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll` and `Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets` from `%windir%Microsoft.NETFramework64v3.5` and ***paste*** into `%windir%Microsoft.NETFrameworkv3.5`

After that restart `Visual Studio` and rebuild the `solution`.